# По какой причине GSON может отдавать null?

Tags: android, rxjava, gson

Имеется стандартная связка в виде API Service (Retrofit + RxJava2CallAdapterFactory, GsonConverterFactory). Почему-то подписка сыпалась с null pointer в onError. Стал разбираться. Оказывается, null возвращается даже если просто запихать gson.fromJson(, ). Такая реакция на любой JSON.

Выдержка из лога:

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://api.npoint.io/0e7fd9aff949ef9f55c4 (1311ms)
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
etag: W/"08b89196d4d9d6dd25645f828b7a8fcd"
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: Render
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-id: 94d2c74d-7c59-4e6f-a3a2-0cddcb208b7b
x-runtime: 0.007044
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Thu, 06 Aug 2020 17:34:48 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"phone_mask":"123123123123123asd"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (35-byte body)
E/ERROR: throw with null exception
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
    at m.a.a.e.a.a(:10)
    at m.a.a.i.c.a$a.a(:16)
    at m.a.a.i.c.a$a.a(:12)
    at e.a.n.e.b.c$a.a(:57)
    at l.x.a.a$a.a(:54)
W/System.err:     at l.x.a.a$a.a(:38)
    at l.x.a.c.b(:48)
    at e.a.e.a(:12267)
    at l.x.a.a.b(:35)
    at e.a.e.a(:12267)
    at e.a.n.e.b.c.b(:32)
    at e.a.e.a(:12267)
    at e.a.n.e.b.g$b.run(:96)
    at e.a.n.g.g.call(:38)
    at e.a.n.g.g.call(:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Покажите код модели данных и как ретрофит инициализирован

Comment: Ну судя по логу у вас включен proguard, вы правила для него написали?